# Why does Core.Std deprecate the `close_in` and `close_out` functions?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

If I `open Core.Std`, trying to use `close_out` function to close an `out_channel`gives me an error because Core changes the type signature of `close_out` to give me a deprecation error message.

```
close_out;;
- : [ `Deprecated_use_out_channel ] -> [ `Deprecated_use_out_channel ] = <fun>
```

**First question:** Why does Core deprecate `close_out` deprecated but not `close_out_noerr`?

**Second question:** Does Core still expect me to work with `in_channel`s and `out_channel`s or does it prefer that I use a different API for IO?

**Third question:** The only other IO API I could find are functions like `read` or `write` in the `Unix` module, which work on file descriptors instead of file handles. In C, the file descriptor functions emit syscalls directly while the ones from stdio.h that receive `FILE *` do buffered IO. Is this similar in Ocaml with the functions in Unix module emitting syscalls directly and the functions working with `in_channel` and `out_channel` do buffered IO?

Comment: it seems that there are 2 functions which could correspond to what you need : `Core.In_channel.close` and `Core.Out_channel.close`. Have you tried these? (I'm not a Core user, maybe these functions are simply aliases)  I also seem to recall that the preferred way is to use `with_file` functions from these modules, since they take care of closing the files afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [Real World Ocaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/imperative-programming-1.html#file-io) book,
the author seems to make extensive use of the `In_channel` and `Out_channel` modules.
Files are no more opened/closed using the Ocaml pervasive functions but with the
`In_channel.close` and `Out_channel.close` functions.

The problem is that if an exception is raised when reading the file, the programmer has to close the opened file when the exception is caught. There is no equivalent of garbage collector for opened files. Using `In_channel.with_file` takes care of proper file closing, even if an exception is raised.

Answer (score 3):

The basic IO is implemeted in `Out_channel` and `In_channel` modules, that defines new interface for the old `out_channel` and `in_channel` types. Since the types are the same it is a thin overlay that interoperates smoothly with any other libraries.

What concerning `close_out_noerr`, it looks like that they just missed it. In genral, you should forget about OCaml Standard Library when using Core, and use only facilities provided by the latter. If you really need old standard library you can use `Caml` module.